# Parse.com Cloud Code Job function calling success but not running function

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a job set up in Parse and I have a bunch of `status.message()` called out so that I can debug whats going on in the function. However when I run the job the code doesnt seem to be executed and none of the messages are being logged.

For some reason though the success function is called.

**Job**

```
Parse.Cloud.job("checkBag", function(request, status) {
    // Gets the current time 
    var MILL_PER_MIN = 60000;
    var now = new Date();
    var minToDate = now.getTime() / MILL_PER_MIN;

    status.message("test");

    // Get all the bags 
    var query = new Parse.Query("Bag");
    // Go though each of them 
    query.each(function(bag) {
        ...
        ...
    },{
        success: function() {
            status.success("Job completed successfully.");
        }, error: function() {
            status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
        }
    });
});
```